# A simple CSS float example

Tags: css, css-float

Have a look at this example pen:

http://codepen.io/benpearson/pen/bHJke

Is it possible to get div Four and Five to move up beside div Two WITHOUT changing the HTML or using absolute positioning?

(I can't use contains as each div will be floated in different directions depending on screen size.)

```
.wrap {
  background-color: #666;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.one {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 110px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.two {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 55px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.three {
  background-color: #bbb;
  height: 35px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.four {
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 20px;
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}

.five {
  background-color: #999;
  height: 20px;
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}
```

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="one">
    One
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    Two
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    Three
  </div>
  <div class="four">
    Four
  </div>
  <div class="five">
    Five
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work for you? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bAzch

Just changed divs four and five to be `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:right;`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just put a container div around divs two and three and move their `float` and `width` properties to it instead.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="one">
    One
  </div>
  <div class="rowtwo">
  <div class="two">
    Two
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    Three
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="four">
    Four
  </div>
  <div class="five">
    Five
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rowtwo {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
}
.two {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 55px;

}

.three {
  background-color: #bbb;
  height: 35px;

}
```

You can see it at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KABoC

Comment: My sincere apologies Michael. I forgot to mention I can't use contains as each div will be floated in different directions depending on screen size. I will update my question with this detail. Thanks very much for your help. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry Ben, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Ben, the div's 4 and 5 will never start from the top 0 of wrapper, because the div 3 starts on  the end of div 2. So 4 and 5 recognize the right-upper corner of div 3 as starting point. You must use position: absolute; .. no other choice as far as I know.